# If $\psi(x,\ldots)$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula then $\neg\psi(x,\ldots)$ if and only if $||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=0$

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

Come from Jech's Set Theory.

**Exercise 14.13**

(i) If $x=y$ then $||\check{x}=\check{y}||=1$ and if $x\neq y$ then $||\check{x}=\check{y}||=0$.

(ii)  If $x\in y$ then $||\check{x}\in \check{y}||=1$ and if $x\notin y$ then $||\check{x}\in \check{y}||=0$.

I use this exercise as a crucial step in Lemma 14.21, and so I think this exercise suggests that

> if $\psi(x,\ldots)$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula then
>
> (i) If $\psi(x,\ldots)$ holds then $||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1$ and
>
> (ii) If $\neg\psi(x,\ldots)$ holds then$||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=0$.

In fact, I have proved it. But I'm still not sure whether this proposition is true since Jech didn't mention it.

**Edit**. I still have some trouble in Lemma 14.21. I want to prove that

> If $\psi(x,\ldots)$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula then $\psi(x,\ldots)$ if and only if $||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1.$

My approach:

Prove by induction on the complexity of $\varphi$. Suppose $\varphi$ is of the form $(\exists x\in\check{y})\psi(x,\ldots)$.
$
\begin{array}{rcl}
||(\exists x\in\check{y})\psi(x,\ldots)||=1&\leftrightarrow&\displaystyle\sum_{\check{x}\in\textrm{dom}(\check{y})}\check{y}(\check{x})\cdot\||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1\\
&\leftrightarrow&\displaystyle\sum_{\check{x}\in\textrm{dom}(\check{y})}||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1\\
&\leftrightarrow&\displaystyle\sum_{x\in y}||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1\\
&\leftrightarrow&(\exists x\in y)||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1\\
&\leftrightarrow&(\exists x\in y)\psi(x,\ldots)
\end{array}
$

But it seems that $\displaystyle\sum_{x\in y}||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1$ doesn't imply that $(\exists x\in y)||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1$ in general, and I don't know the value of $||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||$ since it is possible that $\psi$ is consistent relative to ZFC.

The problem happens in the proof for $\psi$ is an atomic formula as well.

Comment: Yes, it's true. You can prove it by induction on the complexity of $\Delta_0$-formulae or by using the forcing theorem and absoluteness of $\Delta_0$-formulae between transitive models (the latter is overkill, of course). If you post your proof here, we can check it and provide feedback.

Comment: Btw. note that you only need to prove one of (i) and (ii), since $\| \neg \psi \| = \neg \| \psi \|$.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the fact as in your note, and so I just obtained ($\psi$ doesn't hold if and only if $||\psi||\neq 1$), which makes my proof terrible.

Comment: The 'weaker' statement has one advantage that you might be interested in: It holds for forcing via arbitrary posets and not only for (complete) Boolean algebras. But, yeah, in the case of (complete) Boolean algebras, you get a bit more information that also streamlines the proof.

Answer (score 1):

OK I think the followings work, and I found something weird.

The proposiion

> (*) If $\psi(x,\ldots)$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula then $\psi(x,\ldots)$ if and only if $||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1$

is equivalent to

> (**) If $\psi(x,\ldots)$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula then $\neg\psi(x,\ldots)$ if and only if $||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=0,$

so we only need to prove one of them.

But when we use induction on the complexity of $\psi$, these two propositions are different since $\neg\psi$ has more complexity than $\psi$; in this condition, we cannot derive (**) from (*), and vice versa.

Moreover, if we assume (**) in the inductive step, it gives more information than (*), which is weird:

> $
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> ||(\exists x\in\check{y})\psi(x,\ldots)||=1&\leftrightarrow&\displaystyle\sum_{\check{x}\in\textrm{dom}(\check{y})}\check{y}(\check{x})\cdot\||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1\\
> &\leftrightarrow&\displaystyle\sum_{\check{x}\in\textrm{dom}(\check{y})}||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1\\
> &\leftrightarrow&\displaystyle\sum_{x\in y}||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1\\
> &\color{red}{\leftarrow}&(\exists x\in y)||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=1\\
> &\leftrightarrow&(\exists x\in y)\psi(x,\ldots)
> \end{array}
> $

and

> $
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> ||(\exists x\in\check{y})\psi(x,\ldots)||=0&\leftrightarrow&\displaystyle\sum_{\check{x}\in\textrm{dom}(\check{y})}\check{y}(\check{x})\cdot\||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=0\\
> &\leftrightarrow&\displaystyle\sum_{\check{x}\in\textrm{dom}(\check{y})}||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=0\\
> &\leftrightarrow&\displaystyle\sum_{x\in y}||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=0\\
> &\leftrightarrow&(\forall x\in y)||\psi(\check{x},\ldots)||=0\\
> &\leftrightarrow&(\forall x\in y)\neg\psi(x,\ldots).
> \end{array}
> $

So it is easier to prove $(**)$ directly, and eventually we'll have (*) as well.

**Edit.**

Well, it doesn't work for $\psi$ is $x=y$.

Comment: You actually have the other implication in your red marked spot as well: Just note that by our induction hypothesis $\| \psi(\check{x}, \ldots) \| \in \{0,1\}$ for all $x \in y$.